# Adding users to a list via user input C#

Tags: c#, list, class, input

I have a users class which I would like to use to create a list of users until the user no longer wishes to. I don't know how to get input from console. I've deleted my main code as it is a confusing mess and would prefer to start from scratch. My Users class is below.

```
class Users
{
    List<Users> _userList = new List<Users>();

    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    private string _address;
    private string _phone;

    public Users(string name, int age, string address, string phone)
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
        _address = address;
        _phone = phone;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return _age;
    }

    public void SetAge(int age)
    {
        _age = age;
    }

    public string GetAddress()
    {
        return _address;
    }

    public void SetAddress(string address)
    {
        _address = address;
    }

    public string GetPhone()
    {
        return _phone;
    }

    public void SetPhone(string phone)
    {
        _phone = phone;
    }

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Console application?

Comment: what kind of user input ? Console ? Desktop ?

Comment: Sorry, yes Console @saranshkataria

Comment: Seems pretty basic an example. What code did you write that didn't work?

Comment: @saranshkataria I have none at the moment, I got rid of it as I want to understand how it would work. It was a big mess of code which I'm sure was not needed. All I want is to have a while loop, adding users until the user doesn't want to add anymore. It's quite frustrating to say the least

Comment: As an aside, C# by convention uses properties rather than get/set like java or C, and automatic properties avoid the need for explicit backing fields.

Comment: May I know, why do you need console and not a windows form(GUI) support to achieve this?

Comment: I'm just starting out with console applications, I would probably move onto windows form in the future @SivaGopal

Answer (score 1):

First remove List from your Users class and rename it to User.

```
public class User
{
    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    private string _address;
    private string _phone;

    public User(string name, int age, string address, string phone)
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
        _address = address;
        _phone = phone;
    }

    //...
}
```

Then declare List of User classes in console Program class and add new user to the list. Set user properties according to the user console input.

```
List<User> _userList = new List<User>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Age: ");
    int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Address: ");
    string address = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Phone: ");
    string phone = Console.ReadLine();

    User user = new User(name, age, address, phone);
    _userList.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your answer, but I'm trying to complete it as a console application rather than a windows form

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, take note that `List<Users> _userList = new List<Users>();` is unneeded in your class. You're not using it anywhere. A `List<T>` structure is a good way to store multiple users - just replace `T` with a type that represents a user. You should change the name of your class to represent a single user (`User` would be a good idea here) and use a `List<User>` outside of the class.

Take a look at this contrived example, where user has one `string` property - the name of the user. It enables you to add multiple users to a list with names of your choosing and then prints each of the names in a new line. Note that I used an *auto-implemented property* to store the user's name.

```
class User
{
    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Name { get; private set; }
}   

public static void Main()
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    bool anotherUser = true;
    while (anotherUser)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify a name.");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();
        User user = new User(userName);
        users.Add(user);
        string next = Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another user (type Y for yes)?");
        anotherUser = (next == "Y");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nNames of added users:");
    foreach(User u in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(u.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Of course you have to expand on this answer to really get what you want. This is merely a point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a simple use case to get a basic understanding:

As others suggested already you can improve the `User` class as shown below and C# has a concept of [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) and the compiler will handle the getter/setter code generation behind the scenes for you and so at least your code is clean enough!! Again at times you may need to have constructor injected property values or explicit methods to set values and I am not going into that.

```
public class User
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }

   //Other properties/indexers/delegates/events/methods follow here as required. Just find what all these members are in C#!!
}
```

Code to accept user input:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<User> users = new List<User>();

     char createAnotherUser = 'N';

     do
     {
          var user = new User();
          int age;

          Console.Write("\nUser Name: ");
          user.Name = Console.ReadLine();

          Console.Write("Age: ");
          string ageInputString = Console.ReadLine();

          //Validate the provided age is Int32 type. If conversion from string to Int32 fails prompt user until you get valid age.
          //You can refactor and extract to separate method for validation and retries etc., as you move forward.
          while (!int.TryParse(ageInputString, out age)) //Notice passing parameter by reference with 'out' keyword and it will give us back age as integer if the parsing is success.
          {
               Console.Write("Enter a valid Age: ");
               ageInputString = Console.ReadLine();
          }

          //Accept other data you need and validate if required

          users.Add(user); //Add the user to the List<User> defined above

          //Confirm if another user to be created
          Console.Write("Do you want to create another User[Y/N]? : ");
          createAnotherUser = char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey(false).KeyChar); //Compare always upper case input irrespective of user input casing.

    } while (createAnotherUser == 'Y');
```

You can learn more about passing variable by reference using [out keyword in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

Hope this provide you some idea...